# Jquery tabs not showing up

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have included the jquery css & jquery file, still tabs are not showing up.

Code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css"></link>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs1">he</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2">Web2</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#tabs3">Co3/a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs4">Imp</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an extra  block to actually trigger the conversion into a tab control:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css"></link>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs1">he</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2">Web2</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#tabs3">Co3/a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs4">Imp</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tabs').tabs();
</script>
```

Without the additional script section, the div is never transformed into a tab control.

Comment: I have added that part in my external js & included that too but still its not working                                              $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#tabs").tabs(); 
});

Comment: @garima do you see any errors in the console? did you load your external .js before you have loaded jquery+ui?

Comment: I don't see any error & below is the code how I am including files  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css"></link>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>

Comment: I don't see `jquery.js` there you should see an error like `$ is not defined` in the console of your developer tool.

Comment: I forgot to add that line in the code here -- `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css"></link>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>`

Comment: @NicoO :  hey just got an error $(..).tabs() not a defined function

Comment: This comment thread is becoming too long. Please check you relevant assets. My last guess will be, that your "custom" jqueryUi does not contain `tabs()`. Download every lib (complete not customized), check all paths of the files and strictly stick to the Guide on the jQuery pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57678/discussion-between-garima-and-nico-o).